# How to initialize a parameter in javascript? document.getElementById("DataAreaXa")

Tags: javascript, html, parameters

When running my script I get "**Unable to get value of the property 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined**".

From what I found on this forum I need to initialize a parameter.

I have several buttons in my app `<input id=runbutton  type="button" value="&#8594;" onClick="runScriptUp(DataArea1a,DataArea1b,arr1)">` until `DataArea7a,DataArea7b,arr7`.

OnClick function is triggered and parameters passed:

```
function runScriptUp(DataAreaXa,DataAreaXb,arrX){
document.getElementById("DataAreaXa").innerHTML = arrX[2];
document.getElementById("DataAreaXb").innerHTML = arrX[1]*arrX[2];
}
```

Function fetches data from 7 arrays I have `var arr1 = ["Incidents",    Sinc,           0,              0];`, again until `arr7` (arrX[1] has values assigned in `var`s.)

and it should place `DataAreaXa` and `DataAreaXb` values into corresponding `span`s showing values after `onclick` is executed `<span id=DataArea1a name=a>` and `<span id=DataArea1 name=a>` again until `DataArea7a` and `DataArea7b`.

Unfortunately I get "Unable to get value of the property 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined".

I tried to initialize `DataAreaXa` and `DataAreaXb` in `onload` section but writing it 14 times is pointless.
I tried with `for` as well but I guess I'm not doing it right.

```
for (X=1; X<7;X++){
document.getElementById("DataAreaXa")
document.getElementById("DataAreaXb")
}
```

or even

```
for (X=1; X<7;X++){
document.getElementById("DataArea"+X+"a")
document.getElementById("DataArea"+X+"b")
}
```

Can I even use a function to run it 7 times for both `Xa` and `Xb` instead of writing it 14 times?

Thanks. m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you need quotes around your inputs id

```
<input id="runbutton"  type="button" value="&#8594;" onClick="runScriptUp(DataArea1a,DataArea1b,arr1)">
```

Secondly where is your element with an ID of "DataAreaXa" you dont have that anywhere in the code or explain it. You explain how you have a spans called that but you provided no code proving so. So when you do

```
document.getElementByID("DataArea"+X+"a")
```

That is equal to undefined because it you didn't create an element with that ID.

Thirdly you loop will need to go to `X<=7` if you want to include 7.

Fourthly you should initialize your variable used within the loop.

```
for(var X=0;X<=7;X++)
```

The browser might overlook errors 1 3 and 4 but if you don't have an element with an id of `DataArea1a` then you will get a undefined null object returned from the `document.getElementByID`

Comment: No what they are passing in is a DataArea1a NOT "DataArea1a" one is a variable one is a string.

Comment: `DataAreaXa` is a parameter, changes each time different `onclick` is pressed. Undefined is this 
`function runScriptUp(DataAreaXa,DataAreaXb,arrX){
document.getElementById("DataAreaXa").innerHTML = arrX[2];`

Comment: Wait you have more than one button to click? at what point did you make that clear? perhaps you should just put it in a jsfillde or codepen and then we can find the mistakes and fix it because the question as you asked it is not what you think you asked. Just provide us the code you have so far.

Comment: I removed the quotes. `onClick="runScriptUp(DataArea1a,DataArea1b,arr1)` triggers `document.getElementById(DataAreaXa).innerHTML = arrX[2];` making it `document.getElementById(DataArea1a).innerHTML = arr1[2];` Still same issue. inner HTML undefined

Comment: 3rd paragraph: "I have several buttons in my app(...)"

Comment: whole code.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6-dxhfF8qlAT1RyT3ZOVy1oSEU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not downloading anything on my computer, which is what it is asking me to do. Put it in a jsfiddle or codepen like i requested or I give up

Comment: I don't even know where to begin with this, there are 78 errors according to the debugger. Your HTML attribute values are not in quotes, your passing undefined variables into functions as parameters, I think you are trying to pass strings into the functions but they are unquoted. Im not sure where you got this code but it looks like you copy and pasted some template and then tried to make changes to it without a real understanding of how it works. It would probably be easier for me to start from scratch and achieve your goals rather than fix the ridiculous number of errors.

Comment: I made the script/HTA app in VBScript first. It works but with no CSS3 applied. Then I figured "why not js" and started redoing it instead write it from scratch.

Comment: I just wrote this quick code from scratch. its easier than trying to modify a template. http://codepen.io/dustinpoissant/pen/YPeMem?editors=101

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace in your function

`document.getElementById("DataAreaXa").innerHTML = arrX[2];`

by

`document.getElementById(DataAreaXa).innerHTML = arrX[2];`

Hope it helps !

Comment: Nope :'(. Thanks for trying though.